# Firing Datasources

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu, datasource

On my form I have a drop down list that houses employee names. I have a data source that is bound to the drop down list so when you open the form the user is automatically filled in. Above the drop down list I have linkbuttons (A-Z) upon onClick they're supposed to filter through another data source with a sp that filters by letter and output in the drop down list. I know the onClick is firing but the drop down list isn't being populated by the new data. Any suggestions or help would be appreciated. 
Code for each linkButton x26

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkA" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
          Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="#0B446A" Text="A" Font-Underline="True" 
          OnClick="link_click" Font-Bold="True"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Code  behind

```
Protected Sub link_click(ByVal sender As Object, _
             ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
    ColorReset()
    Dim link As LinkButton = sender
    Session("filterletter") = link.Text
    Session("linkclick") = "yes"
End Sub
```

Datasource1

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RequestSystemConnectionString %>" 
                    SelectCommand="userinfo" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:SessionParameter Name="user" SessionField="user" Type="Int32" />
                    </SelectParameters>

                </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Datasource2

```
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RequestSystemConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="current_employees_byletter" 
                SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" >
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:SessionParameter Name="letter" SessionField="filterletter" Type="String" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Datasource1 code behind

```
If Page.IsPostBack = False Then
        Dim dv As New DataView
        dv = SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty)
```

DropDownList1.SelectedValue = Trim(dv.Item(0).Item("userid").ToString)
            TextBox1.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString

Comment: Sounds like you might need to add a line to your code behind ... something like drop down list dot bind to refresh the binding between the drop down list control and the data source.

Comment: Please show the markup for the DropDownList, and the code that binds data to it.

Comment: @nocturns2 I'm unsure of how to exactly bind the drop down list to the new datasource. Datasource1 is databound to the drop down list and reflects the user being selected. My issue is how to bind datasource2 to the drop down list so when the linkbutton is clicked the corresponding names will only be options in the drop down list.

Comment: @jadarnel27 Extra info above might explain better.

Comment: Thanks, that does help.  Could you still edit your question and add the DropDownList markup?  And the markup for the datasuorces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of trying I figured out how to connect the drop down list to the different data sources. Thank you to everyone who viewed and commented. Ultimately I created data views for each datasource in the preRenderComplete.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just change the datasource target of your DropDownList in the link click event:

```
Protected Sub link_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
    ColorReset()
    Dim link As LinkButton = sender
    Session("filterletter") = link.Text
    Session("linkclick") = "yes"
    ' Update the "DataSourceID" field to be the ID of your other datasource
    DropDownList1.DataSourceID = dsEmpByLetter
End Sub
```

Note: if you haven't done it already, you should set the "DataTextField" and "DataValuefield" properties of the DropDownList to the appropriate column names in your datasource.